# sIFR 3 and Links: can't get them to work together

Tags: sifr, hyperlink

I am trying to use font replacement for my links, but have no idea how to do it.

My test site is http://www.internetlinked.com/test/ how do I setup sifr-config.js so that the links on the left have their fonts replaced. I go it to work using

sIFR.replace(decade, {
  selector: 'li',
  css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #1A171B; }'
});

But then I lost all the hover affects and borders

using

sIFR.replace(decade, {
  selector: 'a',
  css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #1A171B; }'
});

results in the replacement but the links don't work

I am using sIFR 3

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach is correct. You can style the link by adding rules to the sIFR CSS:

```
sIFR.replace(decade, { selector: 'li', css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #1A171B; } a { color: #FF9900; a:hover { color: #FF0000; }' });
```

Borders and such would be trickier, since Flash doesn't natively support these. Looking at your design, I would not recommend using sIFR for the links in the sidebar.